# Intermittent Async_ExceptionOccurred errors in a Silverlight 4 app

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0

One of our users received the following unexpected error yesterday whilst using our Silverlight app:

[Async_ExceptionOccurred]
Arguments:
Debugging resource strings are unavailable.  Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem.

Any idea how I start to investigate this?  The problem is intermittent and has so far occurred twice.  We are not using a clientaccesspolicy.xml file as the services and web app are on the same server.  I have looked at the IIS logs for the time the user received the error but cannot see any obvious problems.

Where should I go from here?  I can hardly ask the user to install Fiddler as the problem is very infrequent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting a trace listener on the service will give you a very detailed explanation. Also, if the clients clock is significantly different then the services clock you can get an exception. You can fix that by adding a MaxClockSkew on the service.

Comment: Not sure about the MaxClockSkew suggestion. All of our clients are on the same domain as the server and so there shouldn't be a timing issue. I've just read this: http://sandrinodimattia.net/blog/post/WCF-and-fixing-clienthost-time-issues-(MaxClockSkew)-quickly.aspx

Comment: I was able to get to the bottom of this by using a trace listener on the service.  I will therefore give you the answer.

Comment: @[Myles J] what was the problem?